# convert oracle query to nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

**oracle query:**

select col1,col2 from table1 where col1=12345 order by col2 desc nulls last;

I am using fluent nhibernate. so i have mapping class for table1. i am using code something like this to sorting using nhibernate.

```
criteria
.AddOrder(Order.Desc(
Projections.Cast(
             NHibernateUtil.Decimal, 
             Projections.Property("col1"))));
```

i have to add **nulls last** in above nibhernate sorting code. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation with some workarounds:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1743

And similar for Hibernate:
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-465